# Union polygon in geometrycollection in R

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

from time to time I get shp layer of polygons. For analysis I need intersection between them and another layer of shapefile. Unfortunately most of shp which I get have some topologycal errors. I ussually correct them automatically in qgis (with tool: fix geometry; I tried also st_make_valid in sf) but after intersect with R package "sf" I still got a lot of points and linestring mixed together in geometrycollection type. So my question is how extract and union polygons from geometrycollection in each row.

I tried with this code which work but it is a little ugly. I want some more direct and faster solution. Like you see I prefer work with data.table and sf package together.

```
#intersection of two shp
int=st_intersection(var,ods_g)
setDT(int)

## extract rows with geometrycollection type
int2=int[st_geometry_type(geometry)%in% c("GEOMETRYCOLLECTION")]

## extract rows with polygon in geometrycollection type
int2[, l:=length(st_collection_extract(geometry,"POLYGON")),by = seq_len(nrow(int2))]
int3=int2[l>0]

##union all polygon from geometrycollection in each row
int3[,geometry:=st_as_sf(st_union(st_collection_extract(geometry,"POLYGON"))),by = seq_len(nrow(int3))]


##without converting from sf to sp and back I got error: "Error in CPL_gdal_dimension(st_geometry(x), NA_if_empty) :attr classes has wrong size: please file an issue" what wolud be the reason for that error and what converting to sp 
int3=st_as_sf(as(st_as_sf(int3),"Spatial"))
```

What would be the reason for this error and what does the conversion to sp class make to geometry? Because after converting back from class "sp" to class "sf" error does not show again?

Thank you

Comment: Are they errors with the original shapefiles?

Comment: Hi, yes their original shp have errors